# find_by not behaving as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Working from the rails console, why is the following `find_by` returning nil?

```
2.0.0 (main):0 > Location.last
  Location Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "locations".* FROM "locations" ORDER BY "locations"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
=> #<Location id: 92, district: nil, address: "8026 S KEDZIE AVE", city: "CHICAGO", state: "IL", zip: 60652, website: nil, location: nil, latitude: 41.7474748619454, longitude: -87.7023800625442, location_type: "fire_station">
2.0.0 (main):0 > lat = Location.last.latitude
  Location Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "locations".* FROM "locations" ORDER BY "locations"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
=> 41.7474748619454
2.0.0 (main):0 > Location.find_by( latitude: lat)
  Location Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "locations".* FROM "locations" WHERE "locations"."latitude" = 41.7474748619454 LIMIT 1
=> nil
```

I originally thought it something to do with Sqlite so I switched over to Postgres but still yield the same result.  Someone else working on the some project ran the same `find_by` yielded the proper result.  What is going on with my system that this is happening?

Comment: rounding issues, most likely. Floats are notoriously imprecise.

Comment: @sevenseacat how do I access it precisely?

Comment: What's the datatype in your database?

Comment: @rudolph9 by not storing it as a float, if that is the problem.

Comment: It is being stored as a float.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is a problem with `Float` equality check, here are some suggestions from http://www.mail-archive.com/rubyonrails-talk@googlegroups.com/msg02703.html:

Given:
x = 11.967
y = 11.966999999999 <-- loss of precision due to hex<->decimal 
conversion

1. Compare based on a range (as suggested in a  prior post)
   11.9670 <= x < 11.968.
2. Compare string representations of the floating point values:
   x == y
   => false
   ("%.3f" % x) == ("%.3f" % y)
   => true
3. Store values using a fixed point data type (such as DECIMAL in 
   MySQL):
   lng DECIMAL(5,3)
   x -> lng
   => 11.967
   y -> lng
   => 11.967 <-- rounded based on the rules defined in the database
   Making it safe to compare equality on the two values
4. Store fixed decimal values as integers in the database and convert 
   them when displaying them. I only mention this technique because it is 
   an option for storing currency values. Rather than store dollars, store 
   cents instead and convert to dollars with displaying the values on the 
   view.
   $1.60 -> 160 (in the database)

Comment: I ended up going with _3._, Seemed like the most straightforward way of addressing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As a quick workaround, you could use SQL `ROUND` method

```
Location.find_by("ROUND(latitude, 3) = ?", "%.3f" % lat)
```

but it'll effectively kill your index on the locations table (assuming you have one) and not really suitable for large amounts of data.